# MS SQL Server provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5)

Tags: sql-server, remote-access

I have a server that is running a MS SQL Server 2016 database. I have two other servers: Server A and Server B. I can connect to the database using SSMS on Server A but I can't connect to the database using the same username/password/server name in SSMS from Server B. Here are some facts about Server A and Server B:

1. Server A and Server B are on the same network (Server A IP Address: 
   10.0.0.52; Server B IP Address: 10.0.0.73)
2. the Database server is on a completely different network.
3. Server A has an instance of MS SQL Server 2012 installed on it; Server B does 
   not have MS SQL Server installed on it.
4. Even though I can connect to the database from Server A using SSMS, I can't 
   ping the IP Address of the database server from either Server A nor Server B.
5. There are no firewalls on Server A or Server B.
6. Both Server A and Server B are running MS Server 2012 R2.
7. I have tried using the IP Address from the database server as well as the 
   actual computer name of the database server when trying to connect from 
   Server A and Server B. Both results are the same: I can connect to the 
   database using SSMS on Server A but I can't connect to the database from 
   Server B using all of the same setup I use on Server A.

Here is a screen shot of the error I get when trying to connect to the database using SSMS on Server B (my reputation is too low to paste the screenshot in directly, please follow the link)

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7h895.png)

Something is different between Server A and Server B. I don't know if there is something configured differently between Server A and Server B or if there is a configuration on the database server that is allowing connections from Server A and not Server B. Unfortunately I don't have access to remote into the database server, so hopefully someone will be able to point out what is configured on Server A that allows access to the database server that needs to be configured on Server B to allow connections from Server B. If someone could point out to me what I should check I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have access to the server with MS SQL service? Maybe on firewall on it the traffic is filtered and allowed only from Server A? Maybe the traffic is filtered on the router which you have on the network for Server A and Server B.

Comment: @mariaczi , unfortunately I don't have access to the database server and because of some circumstances I'm trying to keep the project I'm working on really low key so I can't really ask the admin over the database server to look at this with me. So, I guess what I should have emphasized in my OP is what could possibly be configured on Server A that would allow a database connection that I could check on Server B to hopefully get a connection from Server B.

Answer (score 0):

Few things to check...

Is this a SQL Server Express? If yes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37704699/enabling-remote-access-in-ms-sql-server-2012-express

Check if you get the same result trying telnet from srv A and srv B to port 1433 of your sql server (command prompt -> "telnet 10.0.0.52 1433")

Check if both servers have your network marked as private or domain. public might need extra config on firewall
http://woshub.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/network4-public-network.jpg

You wrote that there are no firewalls, but indeed there are - make sure if you have windows firewall turned off (in server manager)